# ctypes to int conversion with variable assigned by reference

Tags: python

```
def t(n):
    print(n)

t(byref(c_int(5)))
```

prints `<cparam 'P' (0000019607137590)>`

how can I convert above printed line to a python `int`? so that it would simply print `5`

I tried with `c_int(n).value`, but didn't cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byref` is for (fast) passing to C level functions; if you need to use the pointer at the Python layer, use `pointer` (slow, but accessible in Python); for pointer types, you dereference with indexing (since this is a single value, it's `[0]`):

```
def t(n):
    print(n[0])
    # Or to get back the c_int without converting to Python int:
    # print(n.contents)

t(pointer(c_int(5)))
```

If you just want to pass the `c_int` within Python though, all `c_int`s are references anyway, so you could just do:

```
def t(n):
    print(n.value)

t(c_int(5))
```

And assigning to or reading from `n.value` will change the caller's `c_int`.